# TWRP RECOVERY in ANDROID

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, twrp, stock-android

I have a doubt that why TWRP Recovery tool is being developed for each smartphone specifically even it does an almost same thing in android phones?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Can we use a TWRP recovery of one brand smartphone another brand smartphone. ? For instance, using Moto X4 TWRP recovery image to the Samsung Galaxy Note 8.

Comment: No, you cannot. TWRP is highly device-specific. See [official FAQ](https://twrp.me/faq/howtocompiletwrp.html).